# How to run GNU Emacs 28 in firejail with the firefox profile?

Tags: permissions, emacs, firejail

I'd like to be able to run GNU Emacs 28 from a Firefox running in firejail, but it gives the following error:

```
emacs: could not load dump file "/usr/libexec/emacs/28.1/x86_64-linux-gnu/emacs.pdmp": Permission denied
```

because of

```
$ ls -ld /usr/libexec
dr-------- 2 nobody nogroup 40 2022-08-22 18:05:49 /usr/libexec
```

The following lines in my `~/.config/firejail/firefox-common.local` file do not solve the problem:

```
ignore blacklist /usr/libexec
noblacklist /usr/libexec
whitelist /usr/libexec/emacs
```

(and `whitelist /usr/libexec` gives an error). Any idea?

**EDIT:** An a workaround to the `/usr/libexec` issue, I can add `noblacklist /usr/libexec` to `~/.config/firejail/firefox.local` since it is run earlier, but the goal is to add everything to `~/.config/firejail/firefox-common.local` since it is more general (run by more profiles), in case I would want to use a different web browser profile.